# Port forwarding with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm hoping someone would be able to help me. I have recently got Raspberry Pi 3 and now I'm trying to set up port forwarding.

Raspberry Pi is connected to my home network via Wi-Fi (wlan0) interface. Eth0 interface of Raspberry Pi is connected to another device, which has HTTP server running on port 80. My goal is to forward port 80 from wlan0 to target device.

```
<wlan0/192.168.2.80> <==> <eth0/192.168.10.10> <==> <target/192.168.10.50>
```

So far it has been a struggle and I can't quite get port forwarding working.

This is the routing table:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.80 metric 303 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.80 metric 303 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.10
```

Here's what I tried:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.50
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE --source 192.168.10.0/24
```

While doing so, I have also set default policy for `FORWARD` to `ACCEPT` via

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

However, I couldn't quite make iptables listening on port 80 of `wlan0`:

```
# curl 192.168.2.80
Failed to connect to 192.168.2.80 port 80: Connection refused
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.10.50 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.50 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.2.80 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.50
```